# Set conditional formatting in SSRS based on value from second dataset

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

Trying to add a conditional formatting expression to one field in my SSRS report based on the value of a second field on my report that comes from a different dataset.

I'm using the following expression but it's not working. Any ideas on how to make this work? Will SSRS allow you to add conditional formatting by comparing fields from different datasets?

```
=iif((Fields!Pay_Hist.Value,"Volumes") = (Fields!UNMGD_PMTS.Value, "Rows"),"Green","Red")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely to be you're not comparing single values.  Both `Volumes` and `Rows` will have more than one result, but one of them (the one that belongs to the current tablix/table etc) is likely grouped so you *can* compare that one value.   However the other dataset has no grouping set, so returns multiple values that cannot be compared.

try adding a aggregate function before comparing like

```
=iif((Fields!Pay_Hist.Value,"Volumes") = First(Fields!UNMGD_PMTS.Value, "Rows"),"Green","Red")
```

alternatively, try writing the value that does not belong to the current tablix to a text box, and in your expression compare against the textbox...

Comment: Thanks trubs.

Each data set contains a single row. I updated the expression with your suggestion and now the error message states there is an incorrect number of parameters for the function 'first'.

Comment: sorry, got the parentheses wrong (now corrected).  This was to only give you an idea to use an aggregate function to go from a number of rows to a single row (even if there is only one row in your dataset), you'll probably need to wrap the first part of the iif() in a First() also?   At any rate, you can add a column to temporarily display each of the values to determine what is actually being tested for equality...

Comment: Made one small modification based on your suggestion and it's now working. Below is the final expression:
=iif(First(Fields!Pay_Hist.Value, "Volumes")=(First(Fields!UNMGD_PMTS.Value, "Rows")),"Lime","Red")
Thanks again trubs.